# How can I come up with a formula for this summation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, induction

I have to come up with a formula for:

$$\sum_{0\le i\le n\text{, i is even}}^\ i^2$$

and then prove it by using induction. I know how to do the proof, but I am stuck on coming up with the formula. I tried using the formula for $\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and then subtracting some multiple of n but I can't figure it out.

I made a table of the sums from $n=0$ to $n=10$ and I could not come up with a pattern.

Comment: Use $\sum_{0\leq i \leq n, i \text{ is even}} i^2 = \sum_{0 \leq i \leq n/2} (2i)^2$

Answer (score 3):

We know that $$\sum_{i=1}^m i^2=\frac{m(m+1)(2m+1)}{6}.$$

Your sum is $$\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} (2i)^2=4\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}i^2.$$

Substitute $m=\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ into the upper formula.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is even $=2m$(say),

$$\sum_{0\le i\le 2m, i\text{ is even}}i^2=4\sum_{0\le i\le m}i^2=4\frac{m(m+1)(2m+1)}6=\frac{2m(2m+2)(2m+1)}6=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}6$$ as $\displaystyle m=\frac n2$

Now assume $\displaystyle f(2m)=\frac{2m(2m+2)(2m+1)}6$

Derive $\displaystyle f(2m+2)$ based on $f(2m)$

If $n$ is odd $=2m+1$(say),

$$\sum_{0\le i\le 2m+1, i\text{ is even}}i^2=4\sum_{0\le i\le m}i^2=\cdots$$  where $\displaystyle m=\frac{n-1}2=\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor$

Now assume $\displaystyle f(2m+1)=\cdots$

Derive $\displaystyle f(2(m+1)+1)=f(2m+3)$ based on $f(2m+1)$

Comment: @Downvoter, please pinpoint the mistake